# Binding ActiveX events within single file Javascript

Tags: javascript, activex

I'm trying to simplify an IE ActiveX project into a single javascript file and I'm having some trouble with ActiveX events for some hardware pieces

The project has them defined as but I would like to move the entire script tag into the js file and allow people to add an EventListener to the event if they need to be notified of it.

The js file is being added as such

```
<SCRIPT ID=clientEventHandlersJS language="javascript" src="./single.js"></SCRIPT>
```

The original synthax (HTML tag) is

```
<script for="Component" event="TargetEvent(args)" language="javascript">Component_TargetEvent(args)</script>
```

The modified synthax (single js file) is

```
Component.TargetEvent = function(args){}
```

Trying to bind the the event itself has not worked. I have tried the following approach but I still get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: Component is not defined"

If I leave the original format in HTML, it works, but moving it to a single js file causes the ReferenceError.

Comment: Is `Component` defined?

Comment: That's the worst part. If I use the HTML tag synthax it works, but if I call Component from JS, it won't work. Activex is not my specialty (Ruby Guy)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with ActiveX.